# How to replace the call to random.randint() in a function tested with pytest?

Tags: python-3.x, random, pytest, monkeypatching

I'm new to programming and did search a lot through the questions but couldn't find an answer to my present problem.

I am writing a little game in python 3.8 and use pytest to run some basic tests.
One of my tests is about a function using `random.randint()`

Here's an extract of my code :

```
import random
...
def hit(self, enemy, attack):
    dmg = random.randint(self.weapon.damage_min, self.weapon.damage_max) + self.strength // 4
```

`hit()` does other things after that but the problem is with this first line.

I tried to use monkeypatching to get a fake random number for the test :

```
def test_player_hit_missed(monkeypatch, monster, hero):
    monkeypatch.setattr('random.randint', -3)
    hero.hit(monster, 'Scream')
    assert monster.life == 55
```

When I run the test, I get this error :

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

From what I understand, the monkey-patch did replace `randint()` by the number I indicated (-3), but then my function `hit()` did try to call it nonetheless.
I thought -3 would replace `randint()`'s result.

Can someone explain me :
- why this doesn't work (I probably haven't correctly understood the behavior of the monkeypatch) ?
- and how I can replace the call to random.randint() by the value -3 during the test ?

Thanks

Comment: Well, the quick and dirty solution would be creating a function that returns `-3`, ie `monkeypatch.setattr('random.randint', lambda a, b: -3)`

Comment: Thank you, it does work. So, if I understand correctly, I have to specify a replacement function when I try to patch a function (now that sounds logical). Why do you think it's dirty ? Is there a better workaround for this problem ? Thanks :)